# Lag over multiple offsets in one query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to identify the largest change over several periods for some time series data. Here's an example data set:

```sql
drop table if exists query_table ;
create temp table query_table (groupcol TEXT, parcol TEXT, daycol Integer, val Integer);

insert into query_table values 
    ('g1', 'p1', 1, 1),
    ('g1', 'p1', 2, 2),
    ('g1', 'p1', 3, 3),
    ('g1', 'p1', 4, 4),
    ('g1', 'p2', 1, 2),
    ('g1', 'p2', 2, 4),
    ('g1', 'p2', 3, 6),
    ('g1', 'p2', 4, 8),
    ('g2', 'p1', 1, 10),
    ('g2', 'p1', 2, 20),
    ('g2', 'p1', 3, 30),
    ('g2', 'p1', 4, 40),
    ('g2', 'p2', 1, 20),
    ('g2', 'p2', 2, 40),
    ('g2', 'p2', 3, 60),
    ('g2', 'p2', 4, 80);
```

The basic query I am doing looks like this (this is for a 1 day lag):

```sql
with
  change_over_time as (
    select groupcol, parcol, daycol,
      (val - lag(val, 1) over (partition by groupcol, parcol order by daycol) ) as change
      from query_table
  ),
  max_change as (
    select groupcol, max(abs(change)) as maxchange
    from change_over_time
    group by groupcol
  )
select * from max_change;
```

Which results in

```
groupcol  | maxchange
----------+------+-----------
 g1       |         2
 g2       |        20
```

What I am doing now is issuing this query and looping through the desired lag offsets in Python, but these queries take a bit of time and I would like to do this in pure SQL. This query would run in Snowflake and I'm ok with Snowflake-specific extensions.

The only solution I have been able to think of is to use Python to generate a query like this:

```sql
with
  change_over_time as (
      
        select groupcol, parcol, daycol, 1 as days,
          (val - lag(val, 1) over (partition by groupcol, parcol order by daycol) ) as change
          from query_table
    
    union all
  
        select groupcol, parcol, daycol, 2 as days,
          (val - lag(val, 2) over (partition by groupcol, parcol order by daycol) ) as change
          from query_table
   
    ),
   max_change as (
        select groupcol, days, max(abs(change)) as maxchange
        from change_over_time
        group by groupcol, days
  )
select * from max_change;
```

So that I have a result like this:

```
 groupcol | days | maxchange
----------+------+-----------
 g1       |    1 |         2
 g2       |    1 |        20
 g1       |    2 |         4
 g2       |    2 |        40
```

But ideally I'd like to run this for many different lags (hundreds, perhaps 1 through 730 days) using only SQL and be able to specify the lags in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure if I've fully understood what you are trying to do.

Though I think you can get your answer without even using lag.

Check if the following meets your requirements.

```
WITH
    day_table(days) AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES (1), (2)) AS x
    )
SELECT
    qt1.groupcol,
    qt2.daycol - qt1.daycol     AS days,
    MAX(ABS(qt2.val - qt1.val)) AS maxchange
FROM
    query_table qt1
        JOIN query_table qt2
             ON qt1.groupcol = qt2.groupcol
                 AND qt1.parcol = qt2.parcol
                 AND qt2.daycol > qt1.daycol
        JOIN day_table dt
             ON qt2.daycol - qt1.daycol = dt.days
GROUP BY
    qt1.groupcol,
    qt2.daycol - qt1.daycol
ORDER BY
    groupcol,
    days
```

Updated to add abs and to have ability to limit to specific ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a table of days that you can base your change_over_time query on. For a variable number of days (say the number of days in the table) this can be done with a recursive CTE (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-ctes-and-hierarchical-data). For a fixed number of days a values clause suffices (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values.html).

Here is your query with an added values clause:

```
with
  day_table(days) as (
    select * from (values (1), (2), (3), (4))
  ),
  change_over_time as (
    select t.groupcol, t.parcol, t.seq, d.days,
      (t.val - lag(t.val, d.days) over (partition by t.groupcol, t.parcol order by t.seq) ) as change
      from query_table t
      cross join day_table d
  ),
  max_change as (
    select groupcol, days, max(abs(change)) as maxchange
    from change_over_time1
    group by groupcol, days
  )
select * from max_change;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. What are the performance implications of that `cross join`? The tables I'm querying are in the order of millions of rows.

Comment: A cross join is  a very simple operation as there are no conditions on which to join. And you don't have a choice anyway :-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my Snowflake instance. I'm getting `SQL compilation error: argument 2 to function LAG needs to be constant, found 'D.DAYS'`

Comment: Also, sorry for the confusion, but I renamed seq to daycol in the question and missed a couple of spots.

Comment: I've been able to get it to run in postgresql but there I get the same values for maxchange in each group independent of the "days".